# How unlock a SQLite3 table?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I'm beginner in SQL/PHP,I want to delete a column from a table with sqlite3, I use this method but when I try to execute it with php I have this error when I execute the query :

```php
$statement = $pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE t1_backup AS SELECT $columns FROM $tableName;DROP TABLE $tableName;ALTER TABLE t1_backup RENAME TO $tableName;");
```

> Error : Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 6 database table is locked

Whereas it works if I manually execute the query...
What's the problem ??

- I tried to add sleep() but nothing...
- I tried to execute query one by
  one but nothing...
- I try to add "BEGIN TRANSACTION" & "COMMIT"

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

check your SQLiteBrowser  or any other editor is on and if there is any unsaved changes.